# How do you install a mac of any kind (dual boot, vm, etc) on a windows 10 computer?

Tags: windows, macos

I am trying to create apps, but obviously you can't on windows. I have searched on youtube so many times and I just need a solution. I tried Yosimite on VMware and it told me the virtual CPU would not work. (Also I have access to a mac if needed for install procedure). Thank you!

Comment: Do an internet search for "Hackintosh".

Answer (score 2):

You can't without running into illegal content like Hackintosh

Please note that Apple allows the use of Mac OS X only on its own devices

Comment: I am fine with using content like that I just need any way to do it